# position multiline left-adjusted axis.text centrally under tick

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, alignment

I have multi-line x-axis labels, which I want left-adjusted within the label (so that the left side of both lines is at the same indentation), but centrally positioned under the axis tick. if I use theme(axis.text = element_text(hjust = 0)), the text lines are properly indented to the same level, but positioned to the right of the tick (see MWE). how do I get them positioned centrally under the tick?

```
library(ggplot2)
    library(stringr)

    ## Create a sample data frame
    df <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                     y = c(2, 4, 3, 5, 6),
                     label = c("Line 1 Label", "Line 2 Label is a bit longer",
                               "Line 3 Label is even longer than the previous one",
                               "Line 4 Label is not so long", "Line 5 Label"))

    ## Wrap the label text with str_wrap()
    df$label <- str_wrap(df$label, width = 15)

    ## Create the plot
    ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
        geom_point() +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5, labels = df$label) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image: labels with hjust = 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `ggtext::element_markdown` which besides `hjust` to align the overall bounding box of the axis text has an additional argument `halign` to align the axis text inside the box, i.e. we could use `hjust=.5` to center the box and use `halign=0` to left-justify the text:

```r
library(ggtext)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

## Create a sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = c(2, 4, 3, 5, 6),
  label = c(
    "Line 1 Label", "Line 2 Label is a bit longer",
    "Line 3 Label is even longer than the previous one",
    "Line 4 Label is not so long", "Line 5 Label"
  )
)

df$label <- str_wrap(df$label, width = 15)
df$label <- str_replace_all(df$label, "\\n", "<br>")

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:5, labels = df$label) +
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(hjust = .5, halign = 0))
```

[image]